# Получение последнего зарегистрированного пользователя из MySQL

Tags: php, users, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Мне нужно получить данные последнего зарегистрированного пользователя:

```
name, login, id, data, time и т.д.
```

Написал такой код:

```
$res3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res3)) {
    $user_next = $r["login"];
    $user_next_profile = "/users/".$r["id"];
    $user_next_data = $r["data"];
    $user_next_time = $r["time"];
}
```

Вроде бы выводит последнего пользователя, но мой код неправильно написан, или мне так кажется?  просто я не понимаю что я сам написал, месяц не писал коды, а опыт небольшой.

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать код, чтобы выводил последнего пользователя в таблице **users**

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

запрос:

```
select * from `users` order by `time` desc limit 1
```

остальное, в общем, правильно. Только цикл вам уже не нужен будет, так как последний пользак всегда один.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.  А цикл убрал, спасибо.

Comment: Дело в том, что у вас он, конечно, выводил последнего пользователя(так как он, чаще всего, в конце таблицы). Но до этого пробегался по ВСЕМ остальным.